# ¿por qué mi elemento <a> no cambia el texto si el script está bien escrito?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

el problema es que tengo una tabla de contenidos, y hay muchos elementos `<td>` que necesitan mostrar mucho más contenido, para eso recurrí al elemento `<a href="javascript:void(0)">` [cuyo `id` es `expandir`] para enlazar el contenido que hay en el `<div>` [cuyo `id` es `casamarron`] y hacerlo expansible, pero el `<a>` al momento de responder lo hace bien sólo en Jfiddle o Codepen, pero no en páginas comunes, o sea, directamente el texto queda igual, ayuda. Gracias de antemano

```js
$('#expandir').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).text('mostrar');
    if($('#casamarron').is(':visible')){
          jQuery(this).text('ocultar');
    }else{
          jQuery(this).text('mostrar');
    }
    $('#casamarron').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="expandir" class="expandir" onClick="javascript:changeText" style="background: none; border: none; color: #5a3696; font-size: 11.5px;">mostrar</a>

<div id="casamarron">
<br>
<img alt="Cash.png" height="24" src="https://static.simpsonswiki.com/images/6/66/Cash.png" style="border-radius: 0px; border: none; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 0px; padding: 4px; transform: translate(-30%, 10%);" width="25"><span inline-block="" style="display: inline-block; transform: translate(25%, -50%);">420 (2º)</span><br></div>
```

Comment: Estas incluyendo jQuery en tu proyecto?

Comment: que es `onClick="javascript:changeText"`? acabo de probarlo y el error que dá es que esa función no existe. Solo quitando eso me ha funcionado.

Comment: hola @alanfcm si, estoy usando jQuery 3.4.1. bajo 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ya validaste que el llamado de tu código se haga después de cargada la librería jQuery?

Comment: hola @AlonsoFallas, mmm creo que no, ¿cómo debería de hacerlo?

Comment: hola @porloscerrosΨ lo voy a probar y te comento.

Comment: Asigna tu codigo al final de la pagina dentro de las etiquetas <script></script> y no en el head, me cuentas como te va.

Comment: @AlonsoFallas te comento que ya escribí el <script> al final del <body> y sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: Agrega tu codigo antes del </body>. El llamado de jquery lo haces en el head, correcto?

Comment: @AlonsoFallas, sí, disculpame, es que me expresé mal en mi anterior comentario, eso justamente quise decir, (</body> en vez <body>), y no, no me funciona

Comment: Si pudieras publicar todo el código de tu página, así sería un poco más fácil ayudarte